# Is there a text editor API providing numbers of lines for enclosing block?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor, atom-editor

I have an idea of a cool tool for pretty much any text editor. To implement my idea I need to be able to:

1. Find the beginning and the end of the block of code where a statement is located. The number of lines for the declaration of the function and the corresponding closing bracket in JavaScript would be the dream.
2. Find every occurrence of the specified variable in a file.

This requires some syntax analysis of the target language. I really don't have much preference for the language of the API and the language being examined. Is there an easy-to-use tool for this?

I've been Googling this question for some time, and haven't found an obvious answer for the easiest way to do what I want. I only have opening code for Eclipse's editor to find the solution in mind right now. Atom's scope Descriptors seem unwilling to return numbers of lines for scope declarations.

Comment: Except for the line count, I think these are already implemented.

Comment: @nitind That is what i figured. My goal is to use calculated line numbers to do what i want. I guess the question might not be clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I needed a proper parser for the target language to build a syntax tree of a file. I ended up using the [esprima](http://esprima.org/) parser for JavaScript in combination with the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor, both of which are easy to delve into.

Also, it seems that the Python compiler provides an easy way to build an AST for Python code.